# Unsupported operand types for: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Rounds():
    P1Roll1 = (random.randint(1,7))
    P1Roll2 = (random.randint(1,7))
    Sum1 = P1Roll1 + P1Roll2
    Dice = input("Player 1's turn. Do you want to roll your 2 dice? (Y for yes
and N for no)  ")
    if Dice == "Y" or Dice == "y":
        print("Player 1 rolled their 2 dice. They rolled a " + str(P1Roll1) + " and a " + str(P1Roll2) + " which totals to " + str(Sum1))
        if int(Sum1) % 2 == 0:
            print("Player 1 got 10 more points for rolling an even sum. " + "\n" + "Player 1 got " + str(Sum1 + 10) + " points")
            Final1 = str(Sum1 + 10)
        elif int(Sum1) % 2 == 1:
            print("Player 1 got " + str(Sum1) + " points")
            Final1 = str(Sum1)
    elif Dice == "N" or Dice == "n":
        sys.exit()
    P2Roll1 = (random.randint(1,7))
    P2Roll2 = (random.randint(1,7))
    Sum2 = P2Roll1 + P2Roll2
    Dice1 = input("Player 2's turn. Do you want to roll your 2 dice? (Y for yes and N for no)  ")
    if Dice1 == "Y" or "y":
        print("Player 2 rolled their 2 dice. They rolled a " + str(P2Roll1) + " and a " + str(P2Roll2) + " which totals to " + str(Sum2))
        if int(Sum2) % 2 == 0:
            print("Player 2 got 10 more points for rolling an even sum. " + "\n" + "Player 2 got " + str(Sum2 + 10) + " points")
            Final2 = str(Sum2 + 10)
        elif int(Sum2) % 2 == 1:
            print("Player 2 got " + str(Sum2) + " points")
            Final2 = str(Sum2)
    elif Dice1 == "N" or "n":
        sys.exit()
    if Final2 > Final1:
        print("Player 2 won round 1 by " + (Final2 - Final1) + " points")
    elif Final1 > Final2:
        print("Player 1 won round 1 by " + (Final1 - Final2) + "points")
    elif Final1 == Final2:
        print("Round 1 was a draw as both players got " + str(Final1) + " points")
```

When this function is run I get an unsupported operand error. I have tried putting `str()` and `int()` in but it gives other errors such as "not all arguments converted during string formatting".

The full error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Rounds()
  File "C:\Users\jacobryan_000\Downloads\Dicegame############# (1).py", line 124, in Rounds
    print("Player 2 won round 1 by " + (Final2 - Final1) + " points")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `Final1` and `Final2` are both `str` values, not numbers. You can't subtract strings. Also, `Dice == "N" or "n"` isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

In line 124, you should convert into `int` to make a subtraction. Then change into `str` to print:

```
if Final2 > Final1:
    print("Player 2 won round 1 by " + str(int(Final2) - int(Final1)) + " points")
elif Final1 > Final2:
    print("Player 1 won round 1 by " + str(int(Final1) - int(Final2)) + " points")
```